# Trouble importing external class in CakePHP 4

Tags: php, cakephp, composer-php

I'm using PHP 7, CakePHP 4, JQuery and JQGrid 4.4.0 to upgrade a WebApplication from PHP 5 and CakePHP 2.

In the old version is a controller named text that imports a third party PHP file with a class in it:

`App::import('Vendor', 'XLSXParse', array('file' => 'xlsx-parse.php'));`

The file is in the "vendors" folder (not "vendor"), since is the default route defined in the cake's config.php file and the file cannot be downloaded using composer (and it has not it's own composer.json either). Also, the file contains a class named XLSXParse.

According to https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/core-libraries/app.html, for the new version of the controller, I cannot use the `import` function. Also, I must modify the composer.json file or include the php file manually, but neither one is working.

I edited composer.json using Eclipse. The autoloads section of the file resulted like this:

```
"autoload" : {
    "psr-4" : {
        "App\\" : "src/",
        "Ext\\" : "vendors/src"
    }
},
"autoload-dev" : {
    "psr-4" : {
        "App\\Test\\" : "tests/",
        "Cake\\Test\\" : "vendor/cakephp/cakephp/tests/",
        "Ext\\" : "vendors/src"
    }
}
```

Of course, I created the src fonder in vendors.

Also, copied and modified the file xlsx-parse.php doing the following changes:

1. The file is renamed XLSXParse, since it's the same name as the class inside the file.
2. Defined the namespace Ext\XLSX in the file
3. The file was copied to the folder vendors/src/XLSX

Afterwards, I executed the command `composer dump-autoload -o` in order to make effective the changes in composer.json.

However, when I add the new class with the keyword use (`use Ext\XLSX\XLSXParse;`), Eclipse tells me that the use cannot be resolved. Also, the new class is not recognized.

Also, I tried using the keyword require in order to include the file manually. Although the path is defined correctly, Eclipse still does not recognize the new class.

Did I missed something or did I something wrong?

Thanks in advance.

''EDIT''

I tried adding another external class using composer (simplexlsx). Although the class is added successfully, it's still not recognized from my App. What is more, when I try to run the app following nmm's advice, I get the following error message: Class "App/Controller/SimpleXLSX not found".

I tried looking in another pages for a solution, but all of them assume CakePHP 3 or lower, because of the App::import method.

Comment: From your description it sounds as if you're having an Eclipse problem first and foremost, at least you haven't mentioned that you're receiving any PHP errors that would indicate an actual error in the code/autoloading setup.

Comment: Now I received a PHP error ("Class App/Controller/SimpleXLSX not found". I didn't tested it before due to another work in the same App.